# Check for an empty variable when using split() in python3

Tags: python-3.x, list, error-handling, split, try-except

If I have for example a line of string like this:

```
line = alfa,bravo,zeta,cookie,dragonball
```

I can create them into a list like this:

```
parts = line.split(",")
```

However, I should be able to deal with an error if the line has "empty" objects, like in the following situations:

```
,coookie,dragonball,alfa
alfa,,dragonball,cookie
alfa,dragonball,cookie,
```

How can I do this? in case of an error, the line would not be included in a list, and the program would give an error message:

```
print("ERROR in line: {}".format(line))
```

I thought about using a try/except, but I don't really know how it should be formatted in this case.

Comment: What about checking for``"" in line.split(",")``?

Comment: You mean like this?    if line.split(",") == "": #report error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
line = "alfa,bravo,zeta,cookie,dragonball"

if "" in line.split(","):

    print("ERROR in line: {}".format(line))
    ## further error handling...
```

Comment: Excellent answer. Thanks a lot!